# Enable Javascript only in one div

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to enable Javascript only for one div?

Example:

```
<!-- Script start -->

<script>...</script>
<div class="stackow">
    ...
</div>

<!-- Script no longer will work -->
```

Comment: What do you want to do exactly ?

Comment: Your question does not make sense at all. What do you mean by JS for only 1 div? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You can't. JavaScript is enabled/disabled and runs on a window basis, you can of course write JavaScript to only modify that particular `div` element if that's what you want.

Comment: @C0dekid There isn't a jQuery tag.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek It was a suggestion since I don't understand his question and what he is trying to achieve. And what do you mean by there isn't a jquery tag?

Comment: Rather the right question would be `How to apply scripts to only a specific div` which is totally possible. You need to provide more details on what are you trying to do .. to get better answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The scope of a JavaScript program running in a webpage is the entire "window" (where window could be a window or a frame).

If you want to limit the effects of the script to a particular div, then the script must be written to identify that div and only change the DOM within it.